# Typescript union of nested type loses key that isn't shared between types

Tags: typescript

I believe this may be along the same lines of [Typescript - union types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563935/typescript-union-types), [Issue with TypeScript typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55334784/issue-with-typescript-typing/55340574#55340574), and [Typescript property does not exist on union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974640/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-union-type) but none of them are the exact same. When a union type is created from `Object.entries...map` it seems to remove keys that aren't shared. Here's some example code:

```
type Params = {
    head1:{
        sub1:{
            a:string
    }},
    head2:{
        sub2:{
            a:string,
            b:number
}}}

(params:Params)=>{
    Object.entries(params).map(([headkey, sub])=>{
        Object.entries(sub).map(([subkey, subval])=>{
            subval.a // <- Works fine
            if('b' in subval)
                subval.b // <- Error, "Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: string; }'"
        })
    })
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=43&pln=13&pc=46#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM5QLxQN4FgBQURUAFhHACYCMAXHocY6gK4BGt9jXxcNqwCAJYA7AOYFGAX0kAaCcTKUATHXncWrFZ25de-IWLkMdxVjWHNkrCAgLTJBAgGMA9sP5RkEYCRcVMUAAUYIgoqDTwSGgAlBgAfNpEAPKsAFYQTsAAdBDCAoIQqMGhMVnIcGCBgQDaihQA1hAgMlAaALqxCWpcKemZOXlChYEa0WUVVdUajc2tbABucAA2HfGJJnOsi0tZcFAA9PtQADwAtFAA6i4I9egAZiIQ3SaCd4EA5KzvUCKb29HPDZEDTbLKsA5HM5QACiCAQ1xaACIYPDIAhQFBPt8KC5ClBhC5gFAIAAPQQeNxQUCQTHYKC8Vr5MQAbigkneiMBREkAOMbN5DnwBC8Pj8gWwdVoOA0UuwDPeIBc72kLTqKmlbHVcpomMV7xkZigVAADPZosyCEA)

Is there any way to overcome this? Is this a bug?

Comment: The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53564915/438273) to the first question you linked addresses this scenario. In your case, you can define a `Sub` type to solve your problem ( `type Sub = { a: string; b?: string; };`) so that the inferred union has all of the optional properties you want to access.

Comment: That answer says that type guards should overcome the problem. My type guard does not work. Though I believe the opening statement is probably the crux of the matter in some way. Ultimately,  I am looking for a way to deal with it based on the types provided without creating a new type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug, although it has effects you don't like in this situation.  When the compiler has to infer a single type from several other types, it will try to synthesize what is called ["the best common type"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#best-common-type).  Often this will be a direct [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all the types involved:

```
interface X { x: string }
declare const x: X;

interface Y { y: string; }
declare const y: Y;

const eitherXY = Math.random() < 0.5 ? x : y
// const eitherXY: X | Y
```

But sometimes at least one of the types involved will be [assignable to](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) one of the other types involved, and in these cases the compiler will infer just the single, more general type instead of a union:

```
interface Z { x: string, z: number }
declare const z: Z;

const eitherXZ = Math.random() < 0.5 ? x : z
// const eitherXZ: X // <-- this is X, not X | Z
```

This works because even though it's not declared as such, `Z extends X`.  Object types in TypeScript are extendible via adding of properties, due to structural subtyping.  And so the compiler decides to infer just `X` instead of `X | Z`.

---

Now in a world where TypeScript had a  perfectly [correct](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) type system based on structural subtyping, there might be no observable difference between the union `X | Z` and just `X` if `Z extends X`.  After all, one might think about types as corresponding to the set of all JavaScript values assignable to that type.  If `Z extends X` then every value of type `Z` is also a value of type `X`, and thus `X | Z` and `X` correspond to the same set of values. In that world, the choice of `X | Z` and just `X` would purely be a matter of how the type is *displayed*.

But we don't live in that world.

One place `X | Z` is observably different from `X` is with [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) of object literals:

```
const xOrZ: X | Z = { x: "hello", z: 123 }; // okay
const justX: X = { x: "hello", z: 123 }; // error, excess property
```

Excess property warnings are technically false positives if you think of them as type errors, so perhaps it's better to think of them as a linter warning instead.

Another place is with when you [use the `in` operator as a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing):

```
declare const x: X;
if ("z" in x) {
    x.z.toFixed(); // error 
}

declare const xz: X | Z;
if ("z" in xz) {
    xz.z.toFixed(); // okay
}
```

This is [known to be technically incorrect](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15256#discussion_r154843152).  After all, the value `{x: "", z: ""}` should be a valid value of type `X` and therefore a valid value of type `X | Z`:

```
const hmm = { x: "", z: "" }
const alsoX: X = hmm; // okay
const alsoXZ: X | Z = hmm; // okay
```

So it should really be an error to imagine that the mere presence of a `z` property implies that it is a `number`.  Neither of the above `in` type guards should work if we were being strict.  But in practice it is very useful to assume that you can use `in` as a type guard (and people tend to want even more; just `xz.z` without first checking `"z" in xz`, but this has [consistently been declined](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39065#issuecomment-643826453)).

---

This all means that, depending on how you think about structural subtyping and unions, and whether or not it matches up with how the compiler treats a type or expression, you are likely to get correct-but-annoying warnings or incorrect-but-useful lack of warnings... neither of which are bugs.

So there's no bug here.

---

That said, what could you do to overcome it?  In your case the problem is that `Object.entries()` has the following call signature:

```
/* (method) ObjectConstructor.entries<T>(o: {
    [s: string]: T;
} | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][] (+1 overload) */
```

And when you call it on `sub`, the compiler infers `T` as `{a: string}`, which is the best common supertype of `{a: string}` and `{a: string, b: number}`:

```
Object.entries(sub)
/* (method) ObjectConstructor.entries<{ a: string; }>(...) */
```

Therefore the most straightforward way to work around it is to explicitly specify `T` to be the union type you were expecting.  You could either write it out as `{a: string} | {a: string, b: number}`, or you could make the compiler compute that type in terms of `Params`:

```
type SubSubParams =
    { [K in keyof Params]: Params[K][keyof Params[K]] }[keyof Params]
/* type SubSubParams = {
    a: string;
} | {
    a: string;
    b: number;
} */
```

and then

```
Object.entries<SubSubParams>(sub).map(([subkey, subval]) => {
    subval.a
    if ('b' in subval)
        subval.b // okay
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwM5QLxQN4FgBQURUAFhHACYCMAXDgcY1KgK4BGt9hTPcdqwBAEsAdgHMGPKAF9JRaQBo5pchQBMdPNx6s2GrlKZ9mg0WKXbDUNnREtkbCAmWNZlt24KhIUAMrt-NngkNExlbCgAbQBpKFEoAGsIEAB7ADNYRBRUAF06YOyYnMik1IyCtCKcmRLk9MyQ3IIAegAqKG9oQMCK9CwtRmMBYXEAbgJpKAAfA2Ih0zHlGyg7Bydx-EnW5oIW9oAKZAhgEhSKAEooAHk2ACsIAGNgAGEUkWGWJ5SEADoIEVMEFQAB4ACoAPn2KU0ykiqH4CzEeSgoI2kxmAEEEEgQAAZIRJMHg850OGIhQo4rVfYAaioUBSADcnAAbFKUS7bXb4B5vARQI4nM6YKD7MBZND5CWoS4YcGzIg3e5PP4A4RAsXS84-ZBwMD7faRMiUUoU3Q5WXyrQuYhKx7AVWA1D7XTnG1ENqiwWnC7XO7217vQSfYDfR3qkEReYjMSjGSQn6Jzk7fDcwx2lX-J3A7rsXqQ106vUGuHsU3MdiMuAsi2YK3upi6Kssn5wBuMIQZfYAcjY3biIgrbGbbssVmITerPzYUGazQZCTgIAb0lHrlHnnw3rO+wixuomiHnCjdG7qX7k0UKko+giulvUGMZ5S3YpyyoAAYZN-VxtuaJgCcNI4AeaAAA0cCgAAPBEYxkAgKEeFlEGgXkg2gugwL-fAAKAkDoAATUgkBYLMOM3EQh5kIQVC+WAKASKgAjsLQ-kICEE4nDAoisAAWTgE4fiQEQKBSZB9kuYEoA-H4AFYoAAfmgqA6GXfA5ygVj6PYziEG4zDpiY-8ATw0CoAALUgmCTBjCkAC9bHsRwEHg-BKOo2j0IciyWLoqAdLIPTLL4gSSCEuARLEiSoCkmT5KUqCVKgOyWnnLT-I4wKwPMzDuXSqCrgQHKoAgmZgqsugACIyBZNlKvsugqDUABmGQ4w0lJFzU9LbhYAQwIM-oMKgaqIFqlJ6uSxqWra2d5ycBBvgpCAoNA1B0DARbIAQUBuXclDNL8qDvNKnz-y7Sq7MqgdoMuAZiCgn47J+UMADEhCgiAKAk9r5uxb4JnO0VLuu+Jjru5Rjqel6Unez7vvOX6FyXQHUx5PySGQZARQiazKsm7z8dc9Lq1QFIBpKkVMeQJHOpR9H0NJ8nitO8rqdprqgA)